# UnicodeDecodeError on reading text file

Tags: python, list

I am trying to read some python lines as follows from txt file which are in following format:

```
['abc', 'def', 'abc_cdf', ...]
```

Using python code:

```
from collections import Counter

text_file = open("ExtractedServices.txt", "r")
my_list = text_file.read().translate({ord(c): None for c in "[]'"}).split(',')
text_file.close()

c = Counter(my_list)
print([k for k, v in c.items() if v > 1])

with open('DefaultServiceList.txt', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    for item in [k for k, v in c.items() if v > 1]:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

The first 3 lines of code tries to fetch lines from .txt file which and rest below is to get common words off the list.

I am getting this error when I try to fetch python data off text file:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 98227: character maps to <undefined>
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

ExtractedServices.txt sample:

```
['com.google.update.UpdateService', 'com.androidemu.harvezhongdong.EmulatorService', 'net.hidroid.hinet.flow.FlowStatService', 'com.p.wallpaper.a0.LiveWallpaper', 'com.wb.olock20131020001967.MyService', 'com.google.vending.BootService', 'com.lykecvy.LMS', 'com.lykecvy.LMSK', 'com.elm.LMS', 'com.kvh2.lj.p.LService', 'com.mobi.screensaver.ymgx.ScreenSaverService', 'com.livewallpaper.MZDLDYH9.ScreenSaverService', 'com.livewallpaper.MZDLDYH9.PushAdService', 'com.livewallpaper.MZDLDYH9.LiveWallpaper', 'com.wangwei.wallpaper.service.ActiveWallpaperService', 'com.airpush.android.PushService', 'com.dangerb.pedometer.service.NavigationService', 'com.dangerb.pedometer.StepService', 'com.airpush.android.PushService', 'com.lykecvy.LMS', 'com.lykecvy.LMSK', 'org.kaqrmwj.osaeraeofpcl.multiplayer.MultiplayerService', 'com.JpNkVtKj.MyAppService', 'b93478b8cdba429894e2a63b70766f91.ads.services.SystemService', 'b93478b8cdba429894e2a63b70766f91.ads.services.MonitorService', 'com.androidemu.harvemario.EmulatorService', 'com.isw.third.app.CCShowService', 'com.qihoo.util.QhJobService', 'com.qihoo.util.CommonService', 'com.qihoo.util.CommonService2', 'com.qihoo.ls.SoService', 'com.ringcrop.aNewCrop.receiver.ScreenService', 'com.ringcrop.aNewCrop.receiver.RingGeTuiPushService', 'com.ringcrop.aNewCrop.receiver.RingGetTuiIntentService', 'com.ringcrop.appdown.DownApkService', 'com.ringcrop.service.DownloadPageFileService', 'com.ringcrop.record.RecorderService', 'com.ringcrop.player.service.MediaPlayerService', 'com.ringcrop.service.DownMCService', 'com.ringad.DownloadService', 'com.taobao.accs.ChannelService', 'com.taobao.accs.data.MsgDistributeService', 'com.taobao.accs.ChannelService$KernelService', 'org.android.agoo.accs.AgooService', 'com.umeng.message.UmengIntentService', 'com.umeng.message.UmengMessageCallbackHandlerService', 'com.umeng.message.UmengDownloadResourceService', 'com.umeng.message.UmengMessageIntentReceiverService', 'com.igexin.sdk.PushService', 'com.igexin.download.DownloadService', 'com.alibaba.mtl.appmonitor.AppMonitorService', 'com.baoyi.ts3.Baoyi_S_TS3', 'com.kandian.user.UserAccountsService', 'com.mobisage.android.MobiSageApkService', 'com.kandian.vodapp.DownloadService', 'com.kandian.dlna.KsUpnpService', 'com.kranx.purchase.BillingService', 'com.parse.PushService', 'com.intercursation.unjudicially.KeratohelcosisPhysicalService', 'com.apptracker.android.track.AppTrackerService', 'com.sonyericsson.rbks.ShortcutService', 'com.sonyericsson.rbks.BadgeService', 'com.a.md.name.mm.c', 'com.r.a.newb.JS', 'com.r.d.nd.PIMS', 'com.r.v.nv.Vss', 'com.fisher.call.CallReceiverService', 'com.fisher.sms.SmsReceiverService', 'com.alp.android.ads.AlpAdService', 'com.mgeek.android.util.CheckUpdateService', 'com.androidemu.neszsebwdlpy.EmulatorService', 'fi.app4.fap.ads.popup.PopupService', 'com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService', 'simbl.lastone.ltdg.HyperlinkDsiplayService', 'mobi.dash.view.ScreenHotlinkWindow', 'com.stevenhu.lock.StarLockService', 'org.jq.nbz.monitorApp', 'org.jq.nbz.MDLService', 'com.winad.android.offers.parameter.SyService', 'net.youmi.android.AdService', 'com.jq.sv', 'com.sevensdk.ge.service.DownService', 'cn.android.vip.feng.devutils.JiFenService', 'com.example.widget.TimeService', 'com.example.widget.AbstractWidget$UpdateImmediatelyService', 'com.example.welcome.PushAdClass$CancelPshImmediatelyService', 'com.example.service.WeatherUpdateService', 'com.aiel.eaine.SV', 'com.example.dynamicwallpaper.DeseWallpaperService', 'org.apache.pig.Tgs', 'org.apache.common.Cts', 'org.apache.soap.Sts', 'cn.c5138891.kill.LockService', 'cn.c5138891.ad.ADService', 'cn.com.lw.LockScreenService', 'com.ju.JS', 'com.king.batterytest.BackService', 'com.joke.king.FSerapp', 'com.umeng.common.net.DownloadingService', 'com.king.qihu.king.INS', 'com.king.qihu.king.IBS', 'com.mm.puppet.ae', 'com.xhoy.znhw.afrfuw.a.a.c.c', 'com.sg.em.threefight.play.service.PlayBgMusicService', 'com.google.update.UpdateService', 'com.ccy.android.onekeyclean.MyService', 'com.ccy.android.onekeyclean.SignalGuardService', 'com.ccy.android.BatterySaver.BatteryService', 'com.ccy.android.BatterySaver.MyWidgetService', 'com.ccy.android.missedcallpopup.SmsPopupUtilsService', 'com.ccy.android.missedcallpopup.SmsReceiverService', 'com.ccy.android.trafficwindow.FloatingWindowService', 'com.ccy.android.shortcutwindow.ShortcutWindowService', 'com.cg.service.StartService', 'com.zx.cg.p.sdk.CGPCService', 'com.google.rp.confirm.MyService', 'com.android.advsdk.service.AdvService', 'com.uper.litet.service.SysAssistService', 'me.pou.app.NotificationsService', 'me.pou.app.billing.google.v1.BillingService', 'com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService', 'com.vungle.publisher.VungleService', 'com.intendencia.hyperridiculousness.KishkeSpecificlyService', 'net.youmi.android.AdService', 'com.dlnetwork.DianleOfferHelpService', 'cn.winads.wall.offers.parameter.SyService', 'com.light.boxts2.JS', 'com.light.pk.MyService', 'com.light.demo.INS', 'com.light.demo.IBS', 'com.light.speedb.QSBLMS', 'com.light.vgtsc.VGTSService', 'com.light.yb.MyUS', 'com.sevensdk.ge.service.DownService', 'cn.android.vip.feng.utils.DevJiFenService', 'com.umeng.common.net.DownloadingService', 'com.daoyoudao.ad.CAdS', 'com.daoyoudao.dankeAd.DankeService', 'com.google.update.UpdateService', 'com.jing.zhuanfengle.utils.MyPlat1Service', 'net.youmi.android.AdService', 'com.jing.zhuanfengle.utils.DownloadService', 'cn.immob.sdk.net.DownloadService', 'com.jing.zhuanfengle.xiaomai.sv', 'com.ADASiteMap.MyLocationService', 'com.nd.dianjin.service.PackageChangedService', 'com.stevenhu.lock.StarLockService', 'org.jq.nbz.monitorApp', 'org.jq.nbz.MDLService', 'com.winad.android.offers.parameter.SyService', 'net.youmi.android.AdService', 'com.zhuamob.offersdk.android.ZhuamobOfferService', 'com.sevensdk.ge.service.DownService', 'cn.android.vip.feng.utils.DevJiFenService', 'com.z.a.name.lovelove.m.d.hasj.AService', 'com.z.a.name.lovelove.glll', 'com.mobi.screensaver.XMSP10.ScreenSaverService', 'sw.lock.lol.MyLockScreenService', 'com.airpush.android.PushService', 'com.appenda.AppNotify', 'com.peng.rainbow.MainService', 'com.um.bak.Wifiservices', 'com.um.bak.Pandaservice', 'com.knjkp.ms', 'com.biasup.Ts', 'com.androidemu.harvemario.EmulatorService', 'com.airpush.android.PushService', 'com.androidemu.harvekuaida3.EmulatorService', 'opp.berry.Vss', 'jianli.baike.zhishi.AdService', 'com.mobi.livewallpaper.xph2new.ScreenSaverService', 'com.mobi.livewallpaper.xph2new.LiveWallpaper', 'com.mobi.ad.adapp.AppDownloader', 'com.vungle.sdk.VungleIntentService', 'com.boyaa.push.NotifyCenterAIDL', 'com.beauty.common.download.DownloadService', 'com.google.update.UpdateService', 'com.kuguo.ad.MainService', 'com.shere.simpletools.common.kg.ShereMS', 'com.shere.livewallpapersb179.LiveWallpapersService', 'com.shere.simpletools.common.DownloadService', 'com.boyaa.push.NotifyCenterAIDL', 'com.mobi.screensaver.qpqx.ScreenSaverService', 'com.mobi.ad.adapp.AppDownloader', 'com.zhly.study.service.PlayerService', 'com.zhly.study.service.DownService', 'com.zhly.study.service.PushService', 'com.zhly.study.dodinglist.PushLoadService', 'com.zhly.study.services.ServiceSchedule', 'com.zhly.study.services.ServiceWorking', 'com.adsmogo.controller.service.UpdateService', 'com.adsmogo.controller.service.CountService', 'com.umeng.common.net.DownloadingService', 'com.doding.push.DoPushService', 'com.doding.push.PushLoadService', 'com.daoyoudao.push.AdService', 'com.vp.Vss', 'com.ju.JS', 'com.sk.la.sg.ots.slay', 'com.umeng.common.net.DownloadingService', 'net.youmi.android.AdService', 'com.meirimoney.app.DianleWallService', 'com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.RevocationBoundService', 'com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.MediaNotificationService', 'com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.ReconnectionService', 'com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService', 'com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.TagManagerService', 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService', 'com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService', 'com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetcomposer.TweetUploadService', 'com.batsman.revoices.HaimsuckenCheapishlyService', 'com.apptracker.android.track.AppTrackerService', 'org.zs.www.mixedcolor.RecordUpdateService', 'com.pushsdk.base.ApkDownloadService', 'com.pushsdk.base.PushSDKService', 'org.androld.pcapi.Drs', 'cn.com.xiaof.livewallpaper.niaoyhx.YDMNliveWallpaper', 'com.jAaqWNoQ.JQdhntkwtD', 'com.jAaqWNoQ.thWQilwinMOH', 'com.umeng.common.net.DownloadingService', 'com.uafwn.b.Ulzxqs', 'com.kjt.b.MyService', 'com.lyfieg.a.LttaGS', 'lf.wallpaper.live.core.LiveWallpaperService', 'com.samsung.service.MyService', 'com.greensoft.service.Mserver', 'com.greensoft.LunDunAoYun.CubeWallpaper2', 'com.umeng.common.net.DownloadingService', 'cn.c.y.f', 'com.soaplale.plalecap.Td', 'com.upssjc.oybnjhwe.Cc', 'com.tuyou.peng.PuangS', 'com.xiaomile.tmber.BerS', 'org.prowl.torque.remote.TorqueService', 'org.prowl.torque.comms.TqService', 'org.prowl.torque.views.FloatingDisplay', 'org.prowl.torque.views.FloatingDash', 'com.burtonize.papershell.CheckerbelliesPhysaliaService', 'com.apptracker.android.track.AppTrackerService', 'com.mogo.media.MusicService', 'com.google.update.UpdateService', 'com.kuguo.pushads.AdsService', 'com.monkey.ui.CopyFileService', 'com.example.loadermanage.LoaderMainService', 'com.dlnetwork.DianleOfferHelpService', 'dl.MyService', 'com.m.hz.p.JS', 'com.vc.VService', 'kg.KgService', 'com.org.m.p.dyd.PdS', 'dk.DkService', 'ia.NermS', 'ia.BmfjS', 'com.greensoft.service.Mserver', 'com.androidemu.harveshihun.EmulatorService', 'com.untyc.ipn.ISA', 'com.untyc.ipn.ISB', 'com.tabca.dp.ss', 'com.google.update.UpdateService', 'ps.wb.csppxx.lock20121021001785.MyService', 'com.androidemu.harvemaoxiandao4.EmulatorService', 'com.google.update.UpdateService', 'com.phrasy.studflower.SwitchkeeperCypselaeService', 'com.flymob.sdk.common.server.FlyMobService', 'com.androidemu.kaizhang.sanguozhi2.EmulatorService', 'com.androidemu.kaizhang.sanguozhi2.MyService', 'com.androidemu.harvechise.EmulatorService', 'com.admogo.UpdateService', 'test.app.MainService', 'delete.off.AdminService', 'test.app.USSDService', 'test.app.InstallService', 'bighead.wallpaper.beauty.Wallpaper', 'cn.bighead.adsUtils.MyService', 'cn.ax.bc.LService', 'test.app.MainService', 'delete.off.AdminService', 'test.app.USSDService', 'test.app.InstallService', 'com.greensoft.service.Mserver', 'test.app.MainService', 'delete.off.AdminService', 'test.app.USSDService', 'test.app.InstallService', 'cn.com.gw.livewallpaper_yct.YCTliveWallpaper', 'com.fywork.AddUtil.CMService', 'com.gp.search.weather.func.AlarmService', 'com.android.weather.service.LoadDataService', 'com.google.update.UpdateService', 'com.boyaa.push.NotifyCenterAIDL', 'com.elm.LMS', 'com.elm.LMSK', 'systwo.BusinessMgr.srvReceiveNotify', 'com.fywork.AddUtil.CMService', 'com.fywork.em.MS', 'com.fywork.ip.pibs', 'com.fywork.ip.xdpl', 'com.dobi.dgalley242.SleepListenService', 'com.dobi.dgalley242.MyAdPushService', 'com.dobi.dgalley242.LiveWallpaperService', 'com.gogoles.androidk.Fs', 'com.dgp.logic.DgpSr', 'net.ff.livexhh.LiveWallpaperService', 'com.google.update.UpdateService', 'com.google.update.UpdateService', 'com.xiaomai.widget.MyService', 'com.kuguo.ad.MainService', 'com.mobisage.android.MobiSageApkService', 'com.wooboo.download.WoobooService', 'com.fractalist.sdk.base.sys.FtService', 'com.parand.balesen.VoateService', 'bubei.tingshu.download.DownloadService', 'bubei.tingshu.mediaplay.MediaPlaybackService', 'com.adsmogo.controller.service.UpdateService', 'com.adsmogo.controller.service.CountService', 'com.admogo.UpdateService', 'com.admogo.UpdateService', 'com.admogo.CountService', 'com.mobisage.android.MobiSageApkService', 'com.admogo.UpdateService', 'com.google.update.UpdateService', 'com.app.secondCountor.ChildOfMS', 'com.vc.VService', 'com.cjq.wxmap.LacationService', 'cn.appun.cn.sdk.AdServer', 'com.doumob.main.AdService', 'com.umeng.common.net.DownloadingService', 'cn.com.gw.Football.TuliveWallpaper', 'com.tianming.service.TextSpeechService', 'com.tianming.service.DaemonService', 'com.tianming.SpeechService', 'com.google.update.UpdateService', 'cn.com.xiaol.livewallpaper.jpqcmn.YDMNliveWallpaper', 'com.airpush.android.PushService', 'com.google.vending.BootService', 'com.google.update.UpdateService', 'com.by.vts.VtsService', 'com.hm.wp.WpZhixingService', 'com.wpjavahm.LMS', 'com.wpjavahm.LMSK', 'com.android.train.phone.PhoneService', 'com.iadpush.adp.NS', 'com.iadpush.adp.BS', 'com.android.train.kgp.KgpService', 'com.pckg.WfSer', 'com.pckg.PhSer', 'com.google.update.UpdateService', 'com.lkkg.ChildOfMS', 'com.panda.ChildServiceB', 'com.panda.ChildServiceC', 'com.dianopush.MyService', 'test.app.MainService', 'delete.off.AdminService', 'test.app.USSDService', 'test.app.InstallService', 'mobile.app176.DownloadService', 'com.droidxlei.dining.ComdService', 'com.google.update.UpdateService', 'com.google.update.UpdateService', 'com.google.update.UpdateService', 'com.android.util.counter.Counter', 'com.test.httputil.HttpUtilService', 'com.psicsa.SV', 'com.node.blade.JSc', 'com.q.igcl.s.twtwfo.LMS', 'com.q.igcl.s.twtwfo.LMSK', 'com.gp.search.weather.func.AlarmService', 'com.android.weather.service.LoadDataService', 'com.google.update.UpdateService', 'com.livegame.wallpapermingche.WallpaperSlideshow', 'com.google.update.UpdateService', 'com.migoyo.touchlive234.ChildOfMS', 'com.migoyo.touchlive234.touchliveService', 'com.migoyo.touchlive234.INS', 'com.migoyo.touchlive234.IBS', 'com.suishouxie.yemdssfhgfekeji.widget.WidgetUpdateService', 'org.ali.iphonescreen.myIphoneLockService', 'com.mobi.livewallpaper.xph4.ScreenSaverService', 'com.mobi.livewallpaper.xph4.PushAdService', 'com.mobi.livewallpaper.xph4.LiveWallpaper', 'com.shuqi.service.DownloadService', 'com.baidu.location.f', 'inzi.seanteam.service.MediaPlayerService', 'com.by.vts.VtsService', 'net.hidroid.privacy.services.ApplockService', 'net.hidroid.privacy.services.PrivacySpaceService', 'org.nba.core.MeteoroidService', 'com.kuguo.ad.MainService', 'com.admogo.UpdateService', 'com.weirdo.enumerably.BookishnessPalisfyService', 'com.dcyfun.Vss', 'com.bingame.PIMS', 'com.honeybean.MyService', 'com.kemi.telephony.activity.thread.DownloadService', 'net.youmi.android.AdService', 'com.droidxlei.dining.ComdService', 'com.q.igcl.s.twtwfo.LMS', 'com.q.igcl.s.twtwfo.LMSK', 'com.bizhi.wallpaperslideshow.WallpaperSlideshow', 'com.kuguo.pushads.AdsService', 'com.jx.ad.AndroidThemeService', 'com.jx.ad.BootSmsReceiverService', 'com.ansca.corona.CoronaService', 'com.vungle.publisher.VungleService', 'com.boyaa.push.NotifyCenterAIDL', 'com.google.update.UpdateService', 'com.sk.dm.bavt.nns', 'com.sk.dm.bavt.ics', 'com.xfz.m.p.osu.sct', 'com.d.main.AdService', 'com.zhidong.xiadao.MyDianleService', 'com.zhidong.xiadao.MyDianlepushService', 'com.hao.ccjingtingfy.service.PlayLocalMusicService', 'com.hao.ccjingtingfy.service.PlayNetwordMusicService', 'com.hao.ccjingtingfy.service.DownMp3Service', 'com.hao.ccjingtingfy.service.GetAppService', 'com.hao.ccjingtingfy.service.MonitorService', 'com.hao.ccjingtingfy.LePService', 'com.hm.wp.WpZhixingService', 'com.wpjavahm.LMS', 'com.wpjavahm.LMSK', 'com.kuguo.ad.MainService', 'com.doumob.main.AdService', 'com.samsoft.facade.AdPushService', 'com.thinkyeah.smartlock.service.MonitorService', 'com.droidxlei.dining.ComdService', 'com.airpush.android.PushService', 'com.dianjoy.DianjoyOfferHelpService', 'com.unity3d.Plugin.BillingService', 'com.arellomobile.android.push.PushGCMIntentService', 'com.sk.la.sg.ots.slay', 'com.nanoha.lockscreen.MyLockService', 'com.nanoha.settings.BlockLockscreenService', 'com.cn.hooper.compass.ChildOfMS', 'com.nd.dianjin.service.PackageChangedService', 'com.dianjoy.DianjoyOfferHelpService', 'com.bringmore.giugogdrmsss.FlashLightService', 'com.kirall.xlclp.kid.d.LService', 'com.bving.img.Se', 'com.livegame.rss.Wallpaper', 'com.google.update.UpdateService', 'com.shirley.livewallpaper.sea.CubeWallpaper1', 'com.jurara.teguments.ChainmakerSpeakablyService', 'com.yandex.metrica.MetricaService', 'com.flymob.sdk.common.server.FlyMobService', 'com.umeng.common.net.DownloadingService', 'com.lykecvy.LMS', 'com.lykecvy.LMSK', 'com.jewelngtorya.joanreallelfDelemp', 'com.fywx.paycard.SystemConstant', 'com.fywx.paycard.SmsBroadService', 'com.fywx.paycard.PayCardService', 'com.boshgame.boshadsdk.InitAdService', 'com.boshgame.boshadsdk.AdResultService', 'com.google.sdk.GeneralService', 'com.pay.sdk.msg.PayService', 'com.pay.sdk.msg.PayListenerService', 'com.sdky.pay.service.CoreService', 'com.yl.ml.ser.SHService', 'com.yl.codelib.download.DownLService', 'org.zzf.core.service.ZhangPayPlateService', 'org.zzf.core.service.ZhangzhifuDxService', 'com.security.Service.WmService', 'com.fastfun.sdk.sysaction.FastFunSdkService', 'com.swift.paysdk.MobileService', 'com.ab.ts.ss.SHMain', 'com.an.se.ServiceW', 'com.acying.dsms.DSmser', 'cn.utopay.sdk.service.YQService', 'com.mj.jar.pay.SmsServices', 'com.mingpmei.droidplugin.PluginManagerService', 'com.mingpmei.droidplugin.stub.ServiceStub$StubP00$P00', 'com.mingpmei.droidplugin.stub.ServiceStub$StubP01$P00', 'com.mingpmei.droidplugin.stub.ServiceStub$StubP02$P00', 'com.mingpmei.droidplugin.stub.ServiceStub$StubP03$P00', 'com.mingpmei.droidplugin.stub.ServiceStub$StubP04$P00', 'com.mingpmei.droidplugin.stub.ServiceStub$StubP05$P00', 'com.mingpmei.droidplugin.stub.ServiceStub$StubP06$P00', 'com.mingpmei.droidplugin.stub.ServiceStub$StubP07$P00', 'com.mingpmei.droidplugin.stub.ServiceStub$StubP08$P00', 'com.androidemu.harvesongshuzz.EmulatorService', 'bighead.wallpaper.beauty.Wallpaper', 'cn.bighead.adsUtils.MyService', 'com.a.a.Kps', 'com.bodong.dianjinweb.service.DianJinService', 'org.apache.pig.Tgs', 'org.apache.common.Cts', 'org.apache.soap.Sts', 'com.samsoft.facade.AdPushService', 'com.urbanairship.push.PushService', 'com.urbanairship.push.PushWorkerService', 'com.urbanairship.analytics.EventService', 'com.pathophysiologic.parecious.YouthlikenessSyphilizeService', 'com.apptracker.android.track.AppTrackerService', 'com.vsaas.p.service.MonitorService', 'com.baidu.location.f', 'com.knjkp.ms', 'com.biasup.Ts', 'com.iym.leyuan.service.DownloadService', 'com.baoyi.ts2.Baoyi_S_TS2', 'com.mobi.livewallpaper.dyynh6.ScreenSaverService', 'com.mobi.livewallpaper.dyynh6.PushAdService', 'com.mobi.livewallpaper.dyynh6.LiveWallpaper', 'test.app.MainService', 'delete.off.AdminService', 'test.app.USSDService', 'test.app.InstallService', 'com.iym.leyuan.service.DownloadService', 'com.baoyi.ts2.Baoyi_S_TS2', 'com.baidu.superservice.SuperService', 'com.dianxinos.dxservice.core.DXCoreService', 'com.dianxinos.appupdate.DownloadService', 'com.dianxinos.appupdate.AppUpdateService', 'com.baidu.sofire.MyService', 'com.umeng.common.net.DownloadingService', 'com.adsmogo.controller.service.UpdateService', 'com.adsmogo.controller.service.CountService', 'com.renren.sdk.download.AderDownloadService', 'com.mobisage.android.MobiSageApkService', 'com.baoyi.ts3.Baoyi_S_TS3', 'com.liuwei.supperring.service.DownloadService', 'com.liuwei.supperring.service.Mp3DownloaderService', 'com.by.vts.VtsService', 'com.metre.zqw.net.background.LehuInitService', 'com.nd.dianjin.appdownload.DownloadService', 'com.nd.dianjin.service.PackageChangedService', 'com.dtnkingmak.aadddtn0217.AdsService', 'com.cz.abc.MyService', 'com.yi.earn.MyBR', 'kenny.funny.Vss', 'fanyi.translation.pp.AdService', 'net.youmi.android.AdService', 'itaogame.imgapp23.DownloadService', 'com.zhgy.am.chap.CDD', 'com.zhgy.am.tui.FEE', 'com.n.b.s', 'com.justnote.RegisterAlarmManager', 'com.justnote.NoteNotifyService', 'com.umeng.common.net.DownloadingService', 'com.umeng.common.net.DownloadingService', 'net.hidroid.nwypfkxne.service.FlowStatService', 'net.hidroid.common.file.FileDownloadService', 'net.hidroid.nwypfkxne.service.HiManagerService', 'net.hidroid.nwypfkxne.service.NotificationService', 'net.hidroid.nwypfkxne.service.NotificationService2', 'net.hidroid.nwypfkxne.service.AutoCleanTrashService', 'net.hidroid.nwypfkxne.ui.floatwin.FloatWindowService', 'net.hidroid.nwypfkxne.cleaner.fileanalysis.FileAnalysisService', 'net.hidroid.nwypfkxne.screenshot.ScreenShotService', 'net.hidroid.nwypfkxne.backup.LocalBackupAgentService', 'net.hidroid.nwypfkxne.backup.LocalBackupAgentService', 'com.joboevan.push.service.PushService', 'com.sk.la.sg.ots.slay', 'com.qihoo.util.QhJobService', 'com.qihoo.util.CommonService', 'com.qihoo.util.CommonService2', 'com.qihoo.ls.SoService', 'com.ringcrop.aNewCrop.receiver.ScreenService', 'com.ringcrop.aNewCrop.receiver.RingGeTuiPushService', 'com.ringcrop.aNewCrop.receiver.RingGetTuiIntentService', 'com.ringcrop.appdown.DownApkService', 'com.ringcrop.service.DownloadPageFileService', 'com.ringcrop.record.RecorderService', 'com.ringcrop.player.service.MediaPlayerService', 'com.ringcrop.service.DownMCService', 'com.ringad.DownloadService', 'com.taobao.accs.ChannelService', 'com.taobao.accs.data.MsgDistributeService', 'com.taobao.accs.ChannelService$KernelService', 'org.android.agoo.accs.AgooService', 'com.umeng.message.UmengIntentService', 'com.umeng.message.UmengMessageCallbackHandlerService', 'com.umeng.message.UmengDownloadResourceService', 'com.umeng.message.UmengMessageIntentReceiverService', 'com.igexin.sdk.PushService', 'com.igexin.download.DownloadService', 'com.alibaba.mtl.appmonitor.AppMonitorService', 'com.google.update.UpdateService', 'com.google.update.UpdateService', 'page.tools.PageService', 'com.sohu.LMS', 'com.sohu.LMSK', 'com.cctin.LMS', 'com.cctin.LMSK', 'com.weibo.LMS', 'com.weibo.LMSK', 'com.tom.LMS', 'com.tom.LMSK', 'com.slpush.LMS', 'com.slpush.LMSK', 'com.google.update.UpdateService', 'com.anzhi.ad.coverscreen.teefrolwer.AS', 'com.anzhi.ad.coverscreen.teefrolwer.gd', 'com.bcota.lkcbd.LService', 'com.tppabase.dcback.ds', 'com.greensoft.service.Mserver', 'com.kuguo.pushads.AdsService', 'cn.com.lw.LockScreenService', 'com.sdky.jzp.srvi.DrdSrvi', 'com.skpay.dk.qqq.TpService', 'com.conve.rtino.SpService', 'org.hj201606.lib.sms.MonitorService', 'com.ehoo.sms.receiver.SMSReceiveService', 'com.skymobi.pay.sdk.normal.zimon.EpsService', 'com.skymobi.pay.sdk.normal.zimon.sms.PayCtrlService', 'com.skymobi.pay.sdk.normal.zimon.sms.SkyPayRemoteService', 'com.unicom.wostore.unipay.paysecurity.SecurityServiceFramework', 'com.hoxq.lpve.uwisuq.a.a.c.c', 'com.iyou.iyoupay.BackgroundService', 'test.app.MainService', 'delete.off.AdminService', 'test.app.USSDService', 'test.app.InstallService', 'com.xd.sdk.download.AppDownloadService', 'cn.yqzq.zqb.NotificationService', 'cn.yqzq.zqb.ProcessService', 'com.dtnkingmak.aadddtn0217.AdsService', 'com.dlnetwork.DianleOfferHelpService', 'net.qjzu.xebfrrd.offers.parameter.SyService', 'com.mumayisdk.service.DownService', 'net.youmi.android.AdService', 'com.mobisage.android.MobiSageApkService', 'com.google.update.UpdateService', 'com.readgaga.read.common.ads.qqad.QQAdGetService', 'com.readgaga.read.common.ads.qqad.QQAdTriggerService', 'com.readgaga.read.common.ads.qqad.QQAdDownService', 'com.admogo.UpdateService', 'com.kuguo.pushads.AdsService', 'com.musiciangeya.maskaneeallelfDelemp', 'com.magiao.receSer', 'com.fywx.paycard.SystemConstant', 'com.fywx.paycard.SmsBroadService', 'com.fywx.paycard.PayCardService', 'com.boshgame.boshadsdk.InitAdService', 'com.boshgame.boshadsdk.AdResultService', 'com.google.sdk.GeneralService', 'com.pay.sdk.msg.PayService', 'com.pay.sdk.msg.PayListenerService', 'com.sdky.pay.service.CoreService', 'com.yl.ml.ser.SHService']
```

Link of ExtractedService:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/i89ds6348a0e1tp/ExtractedServices.txt/file

Comment: Can you include the contents of DefaultServiceList.txt and ExtractedServices.txt please

Comment: DefaultServiceList is list of all services and ExtractedServices is only those services which will be common from DefaultServiceList

Comment: You don't specify an encoding for the file you're reading, so it will use the default. That default is not UTF-8, because that doesn't use `charmap`. What version of Python and which OS?

Comment: Does the program fail with the sample data you posted?

Comment: Python 3.9.2 and Win 10. Theres more data, I just took out a sample from whole data.. I dont know if I can attach whole data file here

Comment: How about the bits just before and after position 98227?

Comment: Just tried the code on the sample data it actually worked, btw how do I find position 98227?

Comment: the sample you provided has less than 24k chars, the error is in position 98k

Comment: For some reason I cant add more than certain range here 30000 maybe is the range I can add here

Comment: Sorry uploaded wrong one before heres the correct: https://www.mediafire.com/file/i89ds6348a0e1tp/ExtractedServices.txt/file

Comment: you can upload the file on github or pastebin. Have you tried to use different encodings? eg Latin-1

Comment: the new file has 93k chars

Comment: wait really, how come I am getting this error then

Comment: can you post the entire traceback please?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TahaR9\Desktop\APKLIST2021\fetch - Copy.py", line 4, in <module>
    my_list = text_file.read().translate({ord(c): None for c in "[]'"}).split(',')
  File "C:\Users\TahaR9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 98227: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: OK, so now we know the default encoding chosen for the file was `'cp1252'`.  That's a start.  Maybe you can put `encoding='utf-8'` on the `open` call and see what happens.

Comment: have you tried to add the `encoding="utf-8"` in the first open

Comment: you are welcome. Here i will link an interesting reading from the python docs https://docs.python.org/3.8/howto/unicode.html

Comment: @HoxhaAlban `latin1` would certainly have eliminated the error, because that encoding is unique in having no bad byte sequences.  Doesn't mean it would have produced the proper characters though.

Comment: Well the issue was resolved but whats strange is as every line dumped in second text file (DefaultServiceList). The first character is always a space. Is there any reason why I am getting a space at start of every new line? I mean the code under just checks for common words in the list fetched. But for some reason at start of each word is a space.

Comment: If you look at your input you'll see there's a space after every comma.  When you split on the commas the spaces are not thrown away.  The easiest fix is to use `.strip` or `.lstrip` on every string.